# Upgrading VM when graphical prompt does nothing

Tags: upgrade, virtualization, vmware

This is my first post, so if I did something wrong I apologize.

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 on VMware player. It tells me to upgrade to 16.04.1LTS. When I click on upgrade and type in my password, nothing happens.

Can you not upgrade OS's in an image? Is there a way around?

I have a lot of work on the image that I don't want to lose by deleting the image and downloading the updated version. Thanks for any help you all can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process for upgrading a virtual machine to the latest version of Ubuntu is the same as a physical machine. Since your graphical upgrade interface is not working, then I would recommend typing the command-line equivalent

```
do-release-upgrade
```

You might need sudo privileges, so the command could be

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This will check for available upgrades and then start the upgrade process. If any errors occur in this process, they will be easier to find and read as opposed to the graphical interface for upgrading.

**I would highly recommend backing up any personal information** to a separate drive/USB/cloud in case anything goes wrong. It's good to get in the habit of this for any upgrade or major changes to an operating system that has personal files.